# Functions are not valid as a React child. I can't find anything in my code that cause this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the parent component with a lot of logic and many other components that are functional components with only return JSX method. I was getting a lot of "Functions are not valid as a React child" errors so I made changes to fixed this and I thought change `{FunctionalComponent}` to `{() => FunctionalComponent()`  should fixed this and yep, most of errors dissapear but there has to be one more thing that cause this error. I tried to debug my code but the debugger doesn't step into childrens (functional components) return methods.

I'll past here the main component render method, and example children component. Maybe I'm doing this wrong because I didnt use functional components before.

Main component render method thats generate quick filters to my filter panel:

```
    generateQuickFilters = () => {
    return this.filterTypes.map(filter => {
        const options = {
            filter: filter,
            maxFilterOptions: this.state.maxFilterOptions,
            toggle: this.toggle,
            toggleCollapse: this.toggleCollapse,
            onShowMoreButtonClick: this.onShowMoreButtonClick,
            hoverIn: this.hoverIn,
            hoverOut: this.hoverOut,
            analytics: this.state.analytics
        };
        return (<QuickFilter options={options} key={UUID.UUID()}/>);
    });
}

render(): React.ReactNode {

    return (
        <div>
            {this.generateQuickFilters()}
            <QuickFiltersModal visible={this.state.isModalVisible} onConfirmClick={this.hideModal}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is how looks one QuickFilter:

```
export interface QuickFilterPropsOptions {
toggleCollapse: (subtype: any) => void;
toggle: (subtype: any) => void;
hoverIn: (subtype: any) => void;
hoverOut: (subtype: any) => void;
filter: any;
analytics: Analytics;
maxFilterOptions: number;
onShowMoreButtonClick: (subtype: any) => void;
}

export interface QuickFilterProps {
options: QuickFilterPropsOptions;
}

export class QuickFilter extends React.PureComponent<QuickFilterProps, {}> {

constructor(props: QuickFilterProps, context: any) {
    super(props, context);
}

render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
        <>
            <div key={UUID.UUID()}>
                <div className='row'>
                    {() => QuickFilterHeader(this.props.options)}
                    {() => QuickFilterOption(this.props.options)}
                    {() => QuickFilterFooter(this.props.options)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

And for example I'll paste here QuickFilterOption functional component that use other functional components:

```
export function QuickFilterOption(props) {
return (
    <>
        <table>
            {() => OptionLabel(props)}
            {() => OptionSubtypeHeader(props)}
            <tbody>
                {() => OptionValues(props)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </>
);
```

Is this the right way to create DOM tree of elements? Any idea what is causing this error? Maybe I shouldn't use functional components?

EDIT1:

```
export function OptionValues (props) {


const generateValue = () => {
    // For each subtype
    props.filter.subtypes.map((subtype) => {
        // Checkbox is disabled when it relates to a property that has no connections or calls
        const disabled = props.option.properties[subtype.property] === undefined; // || option.properties[subtype.property].calls === 0;
        // Checkbox is selected when it is disabled or has a selected property set to true
        const selected = disabled || props.option.properties[subtype.property].selected;

        const classNames: string[] = [];
        // Check if needed
        if (selected) {
            classNames.push('selected');
        }

        const optionValue = () => {
            if (selected) {
                props.option.properties[subtype.property].selected = true;
                props.updateQuickFilters$.next();
            } else {
                props.option.properties[subtype.property].selected = false;
                props.updateQuickFilters$.next();
            }
        };

        // TODO TOOLTIP
        return (
            <td>
                <div className={'ff-checkbox clickable'}><input type={'checkbox'} className={classNames.join(' ')}
                                                                disabled={disabled} onClick={optionValue}/></div>
            </td>);

    });
}

    return (
        <>
            {() => generateValue()}
        </>);
```

}

Comment: how is it related to Angular? XD

Comment: What do You mean? Did I add angular tag? I added four tags only.

Comment: Now only 2 are left XD

Comment: @DominikZ - Your [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56824608/1) had [tag:angular].

Comment: True, my mistake.

Comment: Side note: There's no reason for the fragment around the table in `QuickFilterOption`.

Answer (score 1):

You have several places where you're providing functions as children, such as in the `<div className='row'>` in `QuickFilter`'s `render`:

```
<div className='row'>
    {() => QuickFilterHeader(this.props.options)}
    {() => QuickFilterOption(this.props.options)}
    {() => QuickFilterFooter(this.props.options)}
</div>
```

The children in `<div className='row'>` are all functions. Perhaps you meant:

```
<div className='row'>
    {QuickFilterHeader(this.props.options)}
    {QuickFilterOption(this.props.options)}
    {QuickFilterFooter(this.props.options)}
</div>
```

...although really, it would be better to use those as components (making any necessary changes to the functions to handle that), e.g.:

```
<div className='row'>
    <QuickFilterHeader options={this.props.options}/>
    <QuickFilterOption options={this.props.options}/>
    <QuickFilterFooter options={this.props.options}/>
</div>
```

You have the same sort of thing in `QuickFilterOption`.

Comment: It's interesting becouse when I changed it to `{QuickFilterHeader(this.props.options)}` I got much more `ReactChild` errors :(

Comment: @DominikZ - You haven't shown us `QuickFilterHeader` or `QuickFilterFooter`, but `QuickFilterOptions` would be okay used like the second block above if it didn't also have the same problem. But as I indicated above, really the right solution here is to make them components (functional components or `class` components) and use them as components, not functions.

Comment: Wait, so my actual QuickFilterOption is not a functional component? What did I miss then to make it functional component?

Comment: @DominikZ - Yes, `QuidckFilterOption` looks just fine a functional component other than the unnecessary fragment and the errors calling the functions in its children. So if you fix the issues in it, you should be able to use it as `<QuickFilterOption propName="propValue" />`, etc.

Comment: I've edited my question. There is functional component (?) that is at the bottom of DOM. Can You tell me is it corretly written functional component?

Comment: @DominikZ - No, your `QuickFilterOption` was much closer. The code in the edit isn't at all a functional component. First off, component names must start with a capital letter. Also, a function component has to return the structure for the component. That code doesn't return anything at all. (The `map` callback has a return value, but it's thrown away since nothing uses the array `map` creates.) I suggest stepping back from your current task and carefully working through some basic React tutorials.

Comment: But `export function OptionValues (props)` has the capital letter and this is the name of my component? And also when You scroll down edited part there is `return` method that use `{() => generateValue()}`

Comment: @DominikZ - Sorry, the incorrect formatting threw me off there. (It's **really** worth your time to bother to mark things up correctly, using the tools and help available in the editor.) That return is returning a fragment with a single child **which is a function**. Again: Please work through some basic React tutorials. Compare what you're doing *carefully* with what the tutorials show you to do. They don't show this `{() => example()}` structure for creating children that you're using everywhere.

Comment: Ok now I know what was the mistake. Thanks a lot for Your time!